# navController.popBackStack Jetpack Compose Not working

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, navigationpopbackstack

I have an admin feature where the user is redirected to the adminHomeScreen from a screen for editing contents, now this is a button on the header part of my UI.

Now on my previous code in my common user this code does work

```
`
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HeaderComponentUser(navController: NavController?) {
    TopAppBar(
        colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = Color(0xFFFFD317)
        ),
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    if (navController != null) {
   Log.d("BACK BUTTON", "HeaderComponentAdmin: ERROR NOT WORKING") // Log for test 
                        navController.popBackStack(Screen.Home.route, false)
// THE CODE IS THE SAME IN THE ADMIN SIDE 
  //        navController.popBackStack(Screen.AdminHomeScreen.route, true) // <- 
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    contentDescription = "BACK",
                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowLeft,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp),
                    tint = Color(0xFF000000)
                )
            }
        },
        title = {
            Text(
                text = "",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        },

        )

}'
```

`HeaderComponentUser(navController)`

this is my code for the calling header UI

```
`
navController.popBackStack(Screen.AdminHomeScreen.route, true)


` <- this code doesn't work to
```

Over all the code in the common user is the same as the admin user however it does not navigate back to AdminHomeScreen from the screen for editing contents

Comment: You are not supposed to pass ```navController``` to the ```Compsable```. You can follow best navigation practices https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-nested-navigation-best-practices-978b066c1fb1

Comment: @ChiragThummar but why does it work on my common user but wont work for admin screen?

Comment: i still dont get it please help

Comment: can you please share more code so I can get idea

Answer (score 0):

When you are acting as a common user, and need to go to `Screen.Home.route`, you use parameter `inclusive = false` in function:

```
navController.popBackStack(Screen.Home.route, false)
```

But, when you are acting as a admin, and need to go to `Screen.AdminHomeScreen.route`, you use parameter `inclusive = true` in function:

```
navController.popBackStack(Screen.AdminHomeScreen.route, true)
```

What is `popBackStack()` in our case? This is function, what we can use for movements to back inside `NavController BackStack`, it  and it has two required parameters:

`route` - route of screen what you need to open

`inclusive` - boolean value, when `inclusive = true`, pops (removes) all destinations from top of BackStack to specified in the parameter `route`, **including** specified in the parameter `route`. When `inclusive = false`, pops (removes) all destinations from top of BackStack to specified in the parameter `route`, but **not including** specified in the parameter `route`.

For example:

```
Open Screen1 -> Then open Screen 2 -> Then open Screen 3 -> 
-> Then call navController.popBackStack(route = "Screen2", inclusive = true) ->
-> Screen2 will remove, Screen1 will open

Open Screen1 -> Then open Screen 2 -> Then open Screen 3 -> 
-> Then call navController.popBackStack(route = "Screen2", inclusive = false) ->
-> Screen2 will open
```

I guess, in your case, navigation does not navigate back to AdminHomeScreen from the screen for editing contents due to parameter `inclusive = true`

Comment: navController.popBackStack(Screen.AdminHomeScreen.route, true)

then i should modify this into

navController.popBackStack(Screen.AdminHomeScreen.route, false) ???

Comment: Yes, i guess this will help